# Twilio Hosting - Segregated Hosting

Tags: twilio

Can Twilio be hosted separately (specific to a customer) on the Twilio cloud?

This is for a customer requirement where they want their call details to be segregated and stored separately. Is this possible in Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You won;t be able to host Twilio yourself as it's a cloud platform. What you can do however is have a subaccount for each one of your customers.

This way, their data will be segregated and not displayed with other accounts. This will also allow you or your customers to run reports that are only for that particular account.

All that data is stored in the cloud though, so technically they all live together in the same database.

You can read more about subaccounts [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/subaccounts).

Comment: Thanks Marcos for your response. But some customers (specifically in the financial sector) might have data segregation requirements. They prefer some of their data not being on public cloud (if possible) or at least being separated from other data on the cloud. If this is a requirement, is Twilio not the right solution to propose?

Comment: I suggest contacting support in this case as they may have an alternate solution. One of thing you can do also, is use the delete API to remove the customer's data after you process the requests.